# disable dismissal of uipopoverview controller

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, uipopovercontroller

`UIPopoverController` automatically dismisses when we tap or touch outside the `popoverview`. 
I want to restrict this automatic popover dismissal.

Comment: I've answered below, but this is covered in literally **the third line of the documentation overview**. Please, at least glance at the documentation before posting SOF questions.

Comment: Not sure why this question was down-voted, I find it useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
self.myPopovercontroller.passthroughViews=[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.view];
```

Comment: hi Ravi,i have a doubt i think you already know about answer UIPopoverController not dismissed when opened from navigationItem inside UINavigationController my navigation items back ,filter,sort,setting ...when i click filter navigation item popoverView controller working fine but the problem is if i click other navigation item like back,sort,setting not dismissing ..when we tap or touch on outside navigation bar popover not dismissing how to rectify this problem?

Comment: Not a good solution if you do not want the user to interact with the view below.

Answer (score 5):

Duplicate of "[is there a way NOT to have the popover dismissed when pressing outside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477422/is-there-a-way-not-to-have-the-popover-dismissed-when-pressing-outside-it)"

There is a very simple and legit solution. In the view controller that presents your `UIPopoverController`, conform to the `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` protocol and implement the following delegate method. I just tested this and it does prevent popover to dismiss.

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    return NO;
}
```

Just make sure that you have set the delegate of your popover controller to the view controller that implements this.

You can dismiss the popover by using `[popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];` method.

Comment: +1 @Sam...It would really be better sometimes rather than using self.myPopovercontroller.passthroughViews=[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.view];

Answer (score 3):

Have a read of the [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation. Specifically...

> When displayed, taps outside of the popover window cause the popover
>   to be dismissed automatically. To allow the user to interact with the
>   specified views and not dismiss the popover, you can assign one or
>   more views to the passthroughViews property. Taps inside the popover
>   window do not automatically cause the popover to be dismissed. Your
>   view and view controller code must handle actions and events inside
>   the popover explicitly and call the dismissPopoverAnimated: method as
>   needed.

Answer (score 3):

Implement `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:` in the delegate, and you can stop it from disappearing unless you want it to.