# How to prevent dismissing of the popover control?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I don't want to dismiss popover controller when i touch any view. Is it possible?
I am  using following code for displaying popover controller.

```
UIPopoverController* popoverCamera;

popoverCamera= [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:videoRecorder];

[popoverCamera presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(cropRectangleButton.frame.origin.x,cropRectangleButton.frame.origin.y,0,0) inView:innerview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
NSLog(@"start recording-->%d",[videoRecorder startVideoCapture]);
[videoRecorder startVideoCapture];
[self presentModalViewController:videoRecorder animated:YES];  
[videoRecorder release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Link [disable dismissal of uipopoverview controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898347/disable-dismissal-of-uipopoverview-controller)

When displayed, taps outside of the popover window cause the popover to be dismissed automatically. To allow the user to interact with the specified views and not dismiss the popover, you can assign one or more views to the passthroughViews property. Taps inside the popover window do not automatically cause the popover to be dismissed. Your view and view controller code must handle actions and events inside the popover explicitly and call the dismissPopoverAnimated: method as needed.

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. and more important is i understood the concept.!!

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. Implement the following delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
     return NO;
}
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

implement the pop over delegate

```
/* Called on the delegate when the popover controller will dismiss the popover. Return NO to prevent the dismissal of the view.
 */
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController;
```

Comment: i know this method. but i don't want to dismiss popover when i touch any view.

Comment: return NO in this method, it wont dismiss the pop over.

Answer (score 0):

func popoverShouldClose(_ popover: NSPopover) -> Bool {
return false
}

Answer (score -3):

Try this where you dont want to dismiss the popUp:-

```
[popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No, this dismisses the popover but without animation.